# Unable to parse data bindings through knockout for Bootstrap select picker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, knockout-3.0

This is HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="client" class="control-label">Select the Client:</label>
   <select id="client" class="selectpicker" data-bind="optionsText: 'name', selectPickerOptions: {optionsArray: availableClients}"></select>
</div>
```

and this is my Javascript code:

```
  self.availableClients = ko.computed(function() {
        var clientItem = new Client();
        clientItem.name("Some Name");
        return [clientItem];
    });
```

Although i have defined the availableClients , i get an error - Unable to parse bindings - unable to find availableClients .

It seems pretty forward yet doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding `selectPickerOptions` is not valid unless you are using custom bindings, in that case you need to give us more information like some portion of your custom binding otherwise in [knockoutjs documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), the binding `options` do what I think you want to achieve, so your `select` element would be like:

```
<select id="client" class="selectpicker" data-bind="optionsText: 'name', options: availableClients"></select>
```

And that should work.

Comment: I didnt realize that we have use custom bindings for selectPicker. The code that you provided did work. Ill create custom bindings and then try the select picker options. Thanks!

Comment: If this solve your question, please mark it as Accepted Answer